# local IIs in visual studio 2015 .net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I faced a problem....I need to set IIS to Local IIS under web tab in visual studio.But there  is no local IIS in dropdown list.How I can find it?should I install something?if yes,what should I install and from where?

regards

[image]

Comment: What OS do you have? Search for how to enable IIS for that OS. Mostly it will be under programs and features -> Enable/Disable Features.

Comment: Make sure you have IIS installed on your machine. Try opening with `Inetmgr` in windows run.